# using unix timestamp generate timedelta for babel's format_timedelta

Tags: python, unix-timestamp, python-babel

I am not sure I worded that correctly but python and time always confuses me.
This is what I am trying.
Given a unix timestamp (INT) which is definitely in the past (can be seconds ago or years ago) I want to generate a babel format_timedelta

My problem is

1. Babel format_timedelta takes timedelta as first argument
2. so I guess I need to generate a timedelta using time.time() (now) and the unix timestamp I have.

I can't figure out the part 2 and I believe there must be an easier/correct way to do this. Please share the best possible way to do this, also I need it to be fast in calculating since I have to use it in a web page.

```
def format_starttime(value, granularity="day"):
 delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=time.time() - value)
 return format_timedelta(delta, granularity)
```

gives error in date.format_timedelta()
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'format_timedelta'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime

td = datetime.timedelta(seconds=time.time()-a_unix_timestamp)
```

Comment: thanks I didn't know this about timedelta that I can simply put seconds of unix time and make it timedelta object.

Comment: I tried with your method. but I think I has error :/ (edit and added code)

Comment: I think that the error you're getting has nothing to do with the code that you've shown, because the error is dealing with somewhere that you're doing `<something>.format_timedelta` which doesn't show up anywhere in your shown code.

Comment: yes I have reached the same conclusion sadly. And both of your answers are correct to what i asked.

Answer (score 2):

Difference between two `datetime` instances is a `timedelta` instance.

```
from datetime import datetime
from babel.dates import format_timedelta
delta = datetime.now() - datetime.fromtimestamp(your_timestamp)
print format_timedelta(delta, locale='en_US')
```

See [`datetime` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) for details and more examples.

Comment: yes I have tried both answers and get the same problem. I must point out that I am using Flask and flask ext babel. It just complains of the same problem.